# Delegate stopped working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have two view controllers:

1. `CameraViewController`
2. `CameraPhotoDetailViewController`

I take picture in first one then perform segue to second one and present image to user

I created protocol called `CameraDelegate` in `CameraViewController`:

```
@objc protocol CameraDelegate: class {
    optional func cameraImageReady(#image: UIImage)
    optional func didCloseCameraImageDetailView()
}
```

Both view controllers are implementing this protocol and both have delegates

**CameraViewController**

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, CameraDelegate {

    // MARK:
    // MARK: - Property
    @IBOutlet weak var captureButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var previewView: CameraPreviewView!

    weak var cameraDelegate: CameraDelegate?
    ...
 }
```

**CameraPhotoDetailViewController**

```
class CameraPhotoDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, CameraDelegate {

    // MARK: Variables
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraDetailView: SpringView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraImageNameLabel: UITextField!


    weak var cameraDelegate: CameraDelegate?
    // MARK: -    
    ...
}
```

I assign to those delegates in `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){}` in `CameraViewController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {        

        if let cameraPhotoDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? CameraPhotoDetailViewController {
            println("Segue")
            self.cameraDelegate = cameraPhotoDetailViewController
            cameraPhotoDetailViewController.cameraDelegate = self
        }
    }
```

For some reason delegates work when I am calling protocol method `didCloseCameraImageDetailView()` from `CameraPhotoDetailViewController` but doesn't work when I am calling protocol method `cameraImageReady(#image: UIImage)` from `CameraViewController`.

**Calling from `CameraViewController`**

```
@IBAction func didPressCaptureButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        captureButton.hidden = true

        let videoOrientation =  (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation

self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = videoOrientation

        // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
        CameraViewController.setFlashMode(AVCaptureFlashMode.Auto, device: self.videoDeviceInput!.device)



if let videoConnection = self.stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait

            self.stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {

                    var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    var dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                    var image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!                 
                    self.cameraDelegate?.cameraImageReady!(image: image)       
                 self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Constants.CAMERA_IMAGE_DETAIL_SEGUE, sender: self)
                }
            })
        }
}
```

**Calling from `CameraPhotoDetailViewController`**

```
@IBAction func didPressCloseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    cameraDelegate?.didCloseCameraImageDetailView!()
    //activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I have spend last hour trying to figure out what I am missing but can't really see it. I hope someone here will see it.

Comment: Both delegates are weak, maybe at some point one of the view controller is dismissed, but since delegate is weak, so view controller is removed from memory and delegate become nil? Is this makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know feel like idiot - I was first calling delegate method and then I assigned delegate in `prepareForSegue()`...